# Why can't i turn on installation from unknown apps on my androidtv

Tags: applications, samsung, side-loading

[image: b]

I went to settings, then security and restrictions, then unknown sources. After that i couldn't press on a single thing except back. They're all in gray

Comment: Which Android phone and Android version are you using?